# Is it possible to used some other classes such as some classess in awt or swing in codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone

Is there any way to use some classes in awt or swing in codenameone or not?
If is it yes how is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Developer Guide](https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Docs/CodenameOneDevelopersGuide.html), page 7 — "Limitations and Capabilities", not all Java API classes are supported. In general you cannot simply use arbitrary library classes, just the ones that are supported. Codename One has its own API, whose javadocs can be found [here](https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/index.html). While some classes in that API are under the `java` package, mirroring the Java API, there are no Swing or AWT classes under the `java` or `javax` packages.

However, as explained on the [Codename One for Swing/Java Developers](http://www.codenameone.com/swing.html) page, Codename One's GUI API was heavily influenced and inspired by Swing. Many things will look very similar, or sometimes even identical. For specific details, see the [Developer Guide](https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Docs/CodenameOneDevelopersGuide.html) and [API docs](https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/index.html).

Comment: Great answer. I'd also add that you can write "native code" in Codename One. This effectively means Dalvik code on Android and in the desktop builds you can access AWT/Swing (if you need them) naturally they won't be available on iOS, Android etc. since they aren't ported there and won't make much sense there (not touch friendly etc.)